# logging for proxycommand

Tags: linux, ssh, logs, users

I need to logging users that connected throw bastion host using proxycommand, 
I have used next command:

> $ ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem  user@ip -o "proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p
>   user_bastio@bastion"

In the /var/log/auth.log:

```
Jun 18 10:44:29 bastio_host_name sshd[5064]: Accepted publickey for user_bastio from local_ip port 46806 ssh2: RSA SHA256:
Jun 18 10:44:29 bastion_host_name sshd[5064]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user_bastio by (uid=0)
Jun 18 10:44:29 bastion_host_name systemd-logind[796]: New session 141521 of user user_bastio.
```

Also, I have added

> export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug
>   "$SSH_CONNECTION $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND $(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 |
>   sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]$

to /etc/bash.bashrc , like in https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server , but there no commands that runs via proxycommand in  /var/log/commands.log.

Is it possible to logging users and their commands that used proxycommand?