# ssh jumphost execute always a script

Tags: ssh

i have a ssh jumphost. On the sshjumphost i wanna execute
always a python script if user want use my jumphost to jump.

client1 -------- jumphost ---------targethost

Client use following command:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p test\\\\testuser@jumphost.test.tc" user@targethost
```

I used the server sshd_config and set

```
ForceCommand scriptname
```

But my script dont triggered if a client use the command above.

But if i use following command:

```
ssh user@jump.test.tc
```

then my script was triggered.

What can i do to trigger always a script if a user wanna use my jumphost?

Best regards
mobios

Comment: `/etc/profile` is probably your best bet. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56083/how-to-write-a-shell-script-that-gets-executed-on-login

Comment: possible dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525614/logging-for-proxycommand ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Panki. But if a write a script and put it under /etc/profile.d it would be not trigerred. I tested currenty. I use command ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p test\\\\testuser@jumphost.test.tc" user@targethost. Any Idea ? I need a methode where always a script would be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a script on user level the  you may need to put that script/command in the /home//.bashrc for BASH shell, put to the right file according to the users login SHELL.

## Ex:

[RHuser@LinuxServer ~]$ cat .bashrc

Source global definitions

if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

User specific aliases and functions

uname -a;uptime

[RHuser@LinuxServer ~]$

## Output

[RHuser@Jumpboxserver ~]$ ssh LinuxServer
RHuser@LinuxServer's password:
Authentication successful.
 20:22:16 up 4 days,  8:22,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
[RHuser@LinuxServer ~]$